# azure databricks whitelisting on MondoDB atlas

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-databricks, mongodb-atlas

I whitelisted an Azure Databricks IP address both Control Plan NAT and webapp IP CIDR blocks as described in here:

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html#vnet-inject

on a MongoDB Atlas but I still receive the error below:

com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@1b5a8903.

Is there a way to fix outbound IP address in the cluster instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, recently azure does not support service endpoint for MongoDB Atlas like [Azure Databricks with a Cosmos DB endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/service-endpoint-cosmosdb). If you are using public cloud, you could add the [Azure IP Ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519%20) with filtering your Azure Databricks region in the MongoDB Atlas [Whitelist Entries](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#add-whitelist-entries). Otherwise, you could allow access from anywhere in MongoDB Atlas. Your link is used for whitelisting the traffic on your subnets.

For more details, [another similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018584/azure-databricks-accessing-blob-storage-behind-firewall) for your references.